# French accents in meta tag's content

Tags: php, html, meta-tags, non-ascii-characters

I have french accents in a meta tag's content section. Example:

```
<meta name="description" content="à Québec référence" />
```

When I look at the page source I get:

```
<meta name="description" content="Ã  QuÃ©bec rÃ©fÃ©rence" />
```

I've tried using `&agrave; Qu&eacute;bec r&eacute;f&eacute;rence` but that's how it is displayed in the content section.

I am using 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" />` and I don't think this can change without messing up thousands of characters elsewhere in my project.

How do I get it to look like the first example, is there a php function to use? Thanks.

Also an explanation of why it gets translate to 'Ã  QuÃ©bec rÃ©fÃ©rence' would be nice.

**UPDATE**

I've figured out a solution. Programs like Aptana Studio and Notepad++ were saving the characters in a strange way. I used notepad to edit it and saved it with that and that seemed to solve the problem. Thanks for all your quick responses. Much appreciated. :)

Comment: Do you have UTF-8 encoding set?

Comment: @jtheman No, I'm using iso-8859-1 and I can't change this unless I want to change thousands of lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode the file in the right form, download notepad++ and switch to the correct encoding for french.

Comment: Seeing as an update from the OP suggests other languages, then try: ditto this advice from BeQi, but make encoding utf-8.

Comment: This was actually what would have worked. Didn't see that until now.

Answer (score 5):

Put

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

between your HEAD tag
You can also use 'iconv' under linux to change file encoding. (recommended)

Comment: I've updated my question. I don't think I can change the charset to UTF8 without messing up other characters in the project.

Comment: Well I just personnaly tried switch from ISO to UTF-8 and it worked. I suggest to give it a try

Comment: changing it would cause me to have to rewrite thousands of other characters in the project and possibly a lot of database entries.

Comment: Give it a try? If utf-8 mess other characters in the pages, just roll back to ISO and try other suggestion, like changing you file encoding.

Comment: `iconv -f old-encoding -t new-encoding file.txt > newfile.txt`

Comment: For additionnal flag or parameters refer to http://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv
or `man iconv` on linux

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17513/discussion-between-caleb-doucet-and-pl-audet)

Answer (score 1):

Either your document isn't properly encoded or it has a bad header.

I suggest :

- you check your editor makes UTF-8 (without BOM) documents
- your headers in the HTML file : you should have `<meta charset="UTF8" />`
- the configuration of your server if first two points aren't enough

[Here's the w3.org tutorial on this topic.](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-changing-encoding)

If you really can't change the charset, ensure the charset specified in the `meta` tag is the one of the file. In the short term having this in your header might solve your problem :

`<meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />`

Comment: I've updated my question. I don't think I can change the charset to UTF8 without messing up other characters in the project.

Comment: If you really can't change the charset, ensure the charset specified in the meta tag is the one of the file.

Comment: Not using UTF-8 everywhere in this century is almost often an expensive error leading to many problems. [something to read](http://www.utf8everywhere.org/).

Comment: Yeah, This site was not created by my company and we are trying to cut down the code base by a lot in the future. For now we are trying to do quick bug fixes while the application is live and will rewrite most of the code at a later date.
I've tried adding <meta charset="ISO-8869-1" /> but no luck.

Comment: Extract your part of the code on a different file, and include that file in the big file, and for your own file encode it with utf-8.

Comment: Look at the header of the HTTP response (for example using [Chrome's network panel](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network)) to check the problem isn't in your server configuration.

Comment: I see in the Request Headers section on google chrome's inspector that Accept-Charset has ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3 Does that mean the server isn't the problem?

Comment: What's the charset in the response header ? It should be ISO-8859-1. What's your server ? Apache ?

Comment: [In the link in my answer](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset.en.php), there was a paragraph about server configuration.

Comment: I don't see a charset in response headers. The Content-Type is text/html. Yes, it's Apache 2.2. I'll take a look at the link.

Comment: Dude just do as I say it should work, take aside your bit of code that is needed to a different file, open that file with notepad++, click encode and select utf 8 without bom, save and than upload it next to the old file's location and include it from the old file, that should solve your problem!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to be updated, in html5 you must use 
this

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

for french accent ;)

Comment: Yeah, I know but it is a project built by another company and if I change the charset it will force me to change thousands of lines.

Answer (score 0):

If content comes from mysql database. Use utf 8 connection by querying `"SET NAMES 'utf8'"`

Sometime it happens because of editor's file encoding which is suppose to be UTF-8.